# Store value of $(this) in jQuery variable

Tags: jquery, this

I can't figure out how to store the value of `$(this)` in a variable for use in another function.

In this example I want a reference to the clicked `div` element:

```
function doSomething(thisVar) {
 // do stuff with thisVar
}

$("div.someClass").click(function() {
    var myThisVariable = $(this);
    doSomething(myThisVariable);
});
```

It doesn't work (becomes a NULL reference). What is the proper jQuery syntax?

**Edit:** This error was down to me confusing different instances of `this`. It serves to show that you need to pay extra attention to what `this` really means in each context.

Comment: How are you using "thisVar" ??? just do a simple thisVar.hide(); and you will see if it works or not and make sure to check if you have any JavaScript errors.

Comment: @Alex: I intend to use it just as if I were using `$(this)`. As `$(this)` will mean something else in another function, I need to store it somehow.

Comment: Also, for future questions, please keep in mind that "it doesn't work" does not mean anything and people will _always_ ask you what and how exactly does not work.

Comment: Close the click function correctly: `});` and it works.

Comment: @lanzz: You're right. Figured it would be an easy question, so I omitted that detail. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Alex Ball: Thanks, you're right, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Post some example code for the `doSomething` function to illustrate your usage of `thisVar` and how you find that it has become `null`.

Comment: @lanzz: Will do so when I find the time. Stay tuned... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/j3dn5/2/) Your problem is probably elsewhere.

This IS the proper jQuery way to do it. Very often developers save the value of `$(this)` to a global `self` (or `$self`) to access it in cases where the context and thus the value of `this` changes. Passing it as an attribute is almost the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for setting my head straight. Thanks to everybody's comments, I had to reassess the error and started looking elsewhere for the problem, and sure enough found it.

Answer (score 1):

try some of these

```
function doSomething(thisVar) {
// do stuff with thisVar
    $( '#' + thisVar ) // selects the id
    $( '.' + thisVar ) // selects the class

}

$("div.someClass").click(function() {
    var myThisVariable1 = $(this).attr('id'); //saves the current element id
    var myThisVariable2 = $(this).attr('class'); //saves the current element class
    doSomething(myThisVariable);
});
```

hope it helps :) (hope i understood the question )